# Use jsoup to set the content value of a meta tag

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have an HTML document with a number of meta tags

```
<meta name="donald" content="duck" />
<meta name="micky" content="mouse" />
<meta name="daisy" content="duckling" />
<meta name="scrooge" content="macduck" />
```

I am able to get the content values ok but wish to change "mouse" to "horse" say.

Comment: Is this issue still open?

Answer (score 0):

**Example:**

```
final String html = "<meta name=\"donald\" content=\"duck\" />\n"
        + "<meta name=\"micky\" content=\"mouse\" />\n"
        + "<meta name=\"daisy\" content=\"duckling\" />\n"
        + "<meta name=\"scrooge\" content=\"macduck\" />";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "");

Element mouse = doc.select("meta[content=mouse]").first();
mouse.attr("content", "horse");
```

You just have to select the proper tag and change the attributes value.

**Explanation:**

```
Element mouse = doc.select("meta[content=mouse]").first();
```

Select all `meta`-tags, with attribute `content` with value `mouse`; since `select()` returns a list of tags, `first()` is used to get the first one.

```
mouse.attr("content", "horse");
```

Change value of attribute `content`.

Comment: Sory did not explain fully.  We are given name="micky" and want to chnage content to "horse".

Comment: doc.select("meta[name=micky]").first().attr("content",horse");

Comment: If your problem is solved, please *accept* the answer. Thanks you. :-)